# Is a subset of matrices of a complex field and the real field linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I apologize I do not know how to do matrices in MathJax.

**Question:**

Is the subset $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1+i\\ 3+8i\\ 5+7i\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1-i\\5\\ 2+i\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}i+1\\ 3+2i\\ 4-i\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$ of $\Bbb C^3$ linearly independent when we consider $\Bbb C^3$ as a vector space over $\Bbb C$? Is it linearly independent when we consider $\Bbb C^3$ as a vector space  over $\Bbb R$?

I attempted to use a system of equations but didn't really get anywhere. If someone could please explain this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can compute the determinant by Sarrus' rule.

Comment: Using Sarrus' rule I got to i(32-26i+15i^2)=-2....Feeling like that isnt right. But if it is where do I go from there?

Comment: If the determinant is non-zero, they're linearly independent over $\mathbf C$. Hence over $\mathbf R$ (the converse is not true).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: Check the computation of the determinant. You might be in the case the vectors are linearly dependent on **C** and linearly independent on **R**.

Comment: I'm getting -18 i for the determinant so Bernard's answer applies.